# I no longer detect any OS or hard drive after updating from 12.04 to 14.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I updated the my system from ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04. I had installed the OS on the partition /sda. After I restarted my system, I was taken directly to boot menu and the boot menu no longer showed that /sda partition and said that no OS was installed on my system. I also ran the boot-repair and below is the link for the text generated by it. Please I need help on this ASAP.[Boot-repair](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11800979/)

Comment: Is the drive you call `sda` here the same that is called `sda` in the boot repair output? And what partitions where on there before you did the update?

Comment: What's your disk inventory? Your Boot Repair output shows `/dev/sda`, which appears to be the Ubuntu emergency disk (USB drive or whatnot) and `/dev/sdb`, which is unpartitioned but uses ext4fs and has a label of "data." If you have more than one hard disk, then some are not being detected, which could mean something as trivial as a loose cable or be caused by a serious problem like a broken or missing driver. Also, a filesystem "raw" on a disk with no partitions, although legal, is trouble-prone, so if you've got just one hard disk, that could be the source of the problem.